# VBA: Amplitude of superimposed sine waves

Tags: excel, vba, math, user-input, trigonometry

I have written an excel macro which allows the user to create a graph and then add noise to the data in the form of superimposed sine waves. In order to give the user more control I have made it so that the number of sine waves used and the maximum amplitude of the sine waves are inputs.

The frequency and phase of each sine wave is a random variable between two preset values and the amplitude is a random variable greater than 0 and less than or equal to the user input value for amplitude. So that the maximum possible amplitude does not increase with the addition of more sine waves the amplitude for the individual wave is then divided by the number of waves being used. Each of these variables is generated separately for each of the superimposed waves and then the position of each point is calculated iteratively.

The issue I am having is that when more sine waves are used the probability of the resultant curve being at its maximum at any given point is a lot less and the whole curve has lower amplitude and is closer to the mean. This means the user has to iteratively vary the amplitude until it is as required which is not ideal.

Here is the relevant code:

```
j = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AE19").Value
C = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("AA19").Value
w = 1
For i = 4 To 4003
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I" & i).Value = 0
Next i
Do While w <= C
    A = ((Int((5 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)) / (10 / j) / C)
    F = Int((8 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)
    P = (Int((6 - 1 + 1) * Rnd + 1)) / 6
    For i = 4 To 4003
        x = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("H" & i).Value
        b = Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I" & i).Value
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("I" & i).Value = b + (A * Sin((x / (10 * F)) + (2 * Application.WorksheetFunction.Pi() * P)))
    Next i
    w = w + 1
Loop
```

Where C is the number of sine waves used and j is the maximum amplitude as given by the user.

Also when I allow each value of amplitude to be up to the user defined value (rather than then dividing by C) then the use of more waves increases the amplitude.

If anyone is able to suggest how I can adjust the code so that this does not happen and the expected amplitude of the resultant code remains the same regardless of the number of waves used (however I still want the amplitude of the waves individually to vary).

I’m still quite new to VBA so if you spot any glaring flaws in my code please do point it out.

Comment: If there is a random phase delay as well, is it not normal that the more sine waves used, the closer to the mean the whole curve is?

Comment: Yes it's what you'd expect to see but I was looking for a way round this as its far from ideal for what I want it for.

Comment: If you have chosen a sine wave for a particular purpose, then this is the limitation you are stuck with. Any particular reason you are not adding Gaussian noise or noise from some other distribution?  Also, is there an overall goal to adding this noise? That might help with suggestions.  Finally, there is a statistics Stack Exchange site that might help if the issue is more theoretical than programming

Comment: I am writing an application to demonstrate surface roughness in the scale of microns across a surface. The noise is to add an addition level of roughness to the surface (represented by this graph) after the general shape has been calculated in the previous step. The reason for the sine waves rather than a random scattering of points is so that sequential points remain connected rather than scattered. I was wondering if say, adding the modulus of the sine waves and then removing the least squares of the noise would result in a better graph? Thanks for your help.

Comment: The difficult way would be to iterate through every x value to figure out the wave's actual amplitude.  Then you can scale the wave to get the amplitude you want.